# Is there a polyfill for es6 arrow function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Is there a `polyfill` for es6 arrow function?

the following code throws syntax error exception in IE, is there a `polyfill` to make IE support arrow functions?

```
var myFunc = ()=>{
    alert('es6');
}
myFunc();
```

**Note**: I don't want to use any `transpiler`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This kind of features cannot be polifilled.

Comment: The reason transpilers exist is to solve the problems that polyfills cannot. What is the motivation for avoiding them?

Comment: I have a existing code (spread all over enterprise application) that is getting created/changed my so many developers. So I want seamlessly to allow the developers to use es6 functionalities.

Answer (score 17):

A polyfill can add or fix missing built-in classes, functions, objects... but it cannot modify a compiler's accepted syntax.

Comment: Classes are also new syntax ;)

Comment: I don't agree, creating new variables is not adding new syntax

Comment: `class Foo {}` cannot be parsed by browsers that don’t support classes. But now that I reread the post I guess you meant adding the functionality of built-in classes (though I’m not sure if there are any)? In general I think simply saying that polyfills can add/fix *APIs* is less confusing.

Comment: With classes I did not mean the class sugar syntax, but adding new classes like Promise, for example

Answer (score 14):

There is no polyfill for arrow functions. It is a syntax error to write the code you have unless you use a transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

Features that add new syntax can not be polyfilled.

I can only think of [babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-standalone), which you can think of as a JIT compiler/transpiler (if that is OK with you).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty green with JS so I have a feeling that this may not qualify as a polyfill... but it does seem to be a 'duct tape' stopgap though. I found [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/o8o365yL/) made by [Luis Perez](https://jsfiddle.net/user/luisperezphd/fiddles/) that gives this functionality. I'm still working to better understand arrow functions but it at least does work with one of the [MDN arrow function examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Here's the snippet that after playing with I managed to understand (better at least) lol.  I hope it is useful to someone.

```js
var str = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

var g_arrowCache = Object.create(null);
function arrow(expression) {
  function cache(cache, key, getValueFunc) {
    var value = cache[key];
    
    if(value === undefined) {
        value = getValueFunc(key);
        cache[key] = value;
    }
    return value;
  }
  
  function arrowImpl(expression) {
    // This function is a polyfill for proposed "arrow functions" in JavaScript.
    // Example:  str.map(_$("str => str.length"))
    
    if (expression.search(/\bthis\b/) != -1) throw "'this' not supported";
    
    var indexOfArrow = expression.indexOf("=>");
    if(indexOfArrow == -1) throw "Expressio is missing the arrow operator =>";
    var parametersString = expression.substring(0, indexOfArrow);
    
    parametersString = parametersString.replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
    
    var parameters = parametersString.split(",");
    parameters.map(function(o) { return o.trim(); });
    
    var functionBody = expression.substring(indexOfArrow + 2);
    
    if(expression.indexOf("{") != -1) throw "Use of curly brackets for multiple statements not supported or recommended.";
    if(expression.indexOf("}") != -1) throw "Use of curly brackets for multiple statements not supported or recommended.";
    
    functionBody = "return " + functionBody.trim() + ";";
    var args = parameters.slice(0);
    args.push(functionBody);
    var func = Function.constructor.apply(null, args);
    return func;
  }
  return cache(g_arrowCache, expression, arrowImpl);
}
var _$ = arrow;
console.log(str.map(_$("str => str.length")));
```