# Laravel consoletvs/charts and IE11

Tags: javascript, laravel, ecmascript-6, charts, internet-explorer-11

I'm using [consoletvs/charts](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/) to display charts in my Laravel application.

This works fine in all modern browsers, but I get an `syntax error` (and no charts displayed) in Internet Explorer 11 and below.
Tracing it down it seems this line (from consoletvs/charts, e.g. in [init.blade.php](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/blob/master/src/Views/init.blade.php) line 8) is causing the (initial) error:

```
data => data.json()
```

So the culprit is the arrow operator, not supported in IE11. Using a polyfill seems to impossible (see [Is there a polyfill for es6 arrow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364115/is-there-a-polyfill-for-es6-arrow-function)).

Now my questions:

1. Did I miss a feature in consoletvs/charts?
2. Is there a "Laravel" way to solve this (e.g. using [babel/babel](https://github.com/babel/babel))?
3. Anybody got consoletvs/charts running on IE11?

Comment: If my answer provides helpful information for the issue then I suggest, please accept it as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already got the answer to your question from the suggestion you got on the GitHub issues page for ConsoleTVs/Charts.

> I will be changing this library to use my other tool:
>   https://github.com/Chartisan
>
> This have a babel compilation step on the front-end or a pre-compiled
>   one. Also, the only thing needed will be the fetch() function. This
>   can be polyfilled.
>
> Just stay tunned. I am writting the docs of Chartisan, and this lib
>   will soon be ported to that.

Reference:

[Syntax Error on IE11 #554](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/issues/554)

As suggested, you should wait for the docs of [Chartisan](https://github.com/Chartisan)